# Symfony2 Validation doesn't work on reperated field (password confirmiation)

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, passwords

I am beginner in Symfony2. I read the cookbook, and search on internet, but I don't find the answer on my problem.

Here my Form type:

```
 /**
 * Builds a form with given fields.
 *
 * @param object  $builder A Formbuilder interface object
 * @param array   $options An array of options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'first_name' => 'password',
        'second_name' => 'confirm',
        'type' => 'password',
        'invalid_message' => 'Passwords do not match'
    ));
}
/**
 * Sets the default form options
 *
 * @param object $resolver An OptionsResolver interface object
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Opit\Notes\UserBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}
/**
 * Get the name
 *
 * @return string name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
```

The user is an entity

This is the twig:

```
<form name="changePassword_frm" id="changePassword_frm" method="post">
<div class="modalwindow width-98 default-border height-auto overflow-hidden">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
</div>
```

And the function in my user controller ( It is called by ajax request )

```
public function updatePasswordAction()
{
    $result = array('response' => 'error');
    $request = $this->getRequest();        
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $this->getUserObject($request->attributes->get('id'));

    $form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), $user);

    if ($request->isMethod("POST")) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);        

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
            $newPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($newPassword);

            // Save the user.
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $result['response'] = 'success';
        }
    }
    return new JsonResponse(array($result)); 
}
```

The validation doesn't work, for example if I filled out only the first field (the confirm - second didn't). It was valid!... So the valid() method doesn't check that the two fields' value are equal or not...

However, if I fill out only the 'password' field and 'confirm' field not... Then the password in the database will be the hashed empty string.
If I fill out both, and they are same. It will be the given password in the database. (It works, because I can login with that into my page).

But I don't know, why doesn't work the validation? And Why I didn't get back any error message? 
I checked, and always go into the isValid() method... always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using first_options and second_options as your parameters. It looks like you're using first_name and second_name. Try changing your FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm'),
        'invalid_message' => 'Passwords do not match'
    ));
}
```

This will give you the name of the field through the actual field, instead of JUST the name of the field. Validation is included by default this method.

Comment: Almost, the only one problem, that It doesn't show the invalid message.

Comment: You sure you're not leaving that off of the Twig? Do {{ form(form) }} or {{ form_row(form.password) }} and that would include the form_error section that I think you're missing.